# Webinar | Sitecore SXA Integration With ISOTOPE | Nov 16, 2019

Tags: discussion, community-event

**When:** Saturday, 16th November 2019 at 12 noon IST

**Where:** https://gotomeet.me/sugbangalore

**Agenda:**

Pradeep Shukla will be deep diving the Sitecore SXA capability and will be explaining how RTM can be reduced using Sitecore SXA.
Pradeep will explain how can you quickly integrate Isotope with Sitecore SXA.
https://isotope.metafizzy.co

**About the Speaker:**

[image]

[Pradeep Shukla](http://%20https://www.linkedin.com/in/shuklapradeep/) is Sitecore Certified Architect, Digital Marketing specialist; As a Director of Technology, he is facilitating the digital marketing strategy for top-notch clients of Dubai across sector such as holding, destination, retails, malls. Pradeep enables the community to learn Sitecore via his blog https://learningsitecorecms.blogspot.com/

Pradeep Shukla is a co-founder for Sitecore User Group UAE (Dubai) http://suguae.net/

LinkedIn – https://www.linkedin.com/in/shuklapradeep/

Twitter – https://twitter.com/pradsir